# MSSQL Select Distinct and Sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which returns distinct records on 2 columns, however I need to sort the results on those 2 columnns and 1 additional column.
When I try the SQL below I get the error shown.

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vers, revs FROM tblMVer 
WHERE mid = 194 ORDER BY date_deployed DESC, vers DESC, revs DESC
```

Error:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this please.

Thanks

Kev

Comment: add date_deployed in select statement or remove from order by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cann't order by Date simply because they are different I guess.
But if you will take last date, you can do like this:

```
SELECT vers, revs 
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(date_deployed) AS d, vers, revs 
    FROM tblMVer 
    WHERE mid = 194 
    GROUP BY vers, revs 
    ORDER BY d DESC, vers DESC, revs DESC
) AS temp
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no **date_deployed**  in select

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT vers, revs
FROM tblMVer 
WHERE mid = 194 
ORDER BY vers,revs DESC
```

but Still you want to order by date_deployed

Try this

```
SELECT vers, revs
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT vers, revs,date_deployed 
    FROM tblMVer 
    WHERE mid = 194 
    ORDER BY vers,revs,date_deployed  DESC
) AS S
```

Comment: You have to put the keywords on each column in an `ORDER BY` - your version will give a different sort order than the original.

Answer (score 1):

Order By clause can have only those fields which are being selected, so in order to use order by on `date_deployed` add it to the select statement.

Answer (score 1):

No need if there all the columns is in same order, if these are in different order then need to specify

```
SELECT DISTINCT vers, revs FROM tblMVer 
WHERE mid = 194 ORDER BY  vers , revs DESC
```

Comment: You have to put the keywords on each column in an `ORDER BY` - your version will give a different sort order than the original.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following query to get your result

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblMVer.vers,
tblMVer.revs 
FROM tblMVer 
WHERE mid = 194 
ORDER BY tblMVer.date_deployed DESC, 
tblMVer.vers DESC, 
tblMVer.revs DESC
```

Comment: Um, this is functionally identical to his original query, which is explicitly not working.  What makes you think merely qualifying the table (which isn't necessary in single-table-reference queries) will make his query work?